# How can I get source code of a method dynamically and also which file is this method locate in

Tags: ruby

I would like to know whether I can get source code a method on the fly, and whether I can get which file is this method in.

like

```
A.new.method(:a).SOURCE_CODE
A.new.method(:a).FILE
```

Answer (score 146, accepted):

Use `source_location`:

```
class A
  def foo
  end
end

file, line = A.instance_method(:foo).source_location
# or
file, line = A.new.method(:foo).source_location
puts "Method foo is defined in #{file}, line #{line}"
# => "Method foo is defined in temp.rb, line 2"
```

Note that for builtin methods, `source_location` returns `nil`. If want to check out the C source code (have fun!), you'll have to look for the right C file (they're more or less organized by class) and find the `rb_define_method` for the method (towards the end of the file).

In Ruby 1.8 this method does not exist, but you can use [this gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/method_source).

Comment: Hi, I am from the future, using Ruby 2.6.1!
I want the source code of `String#include?`. So far
`String.instance_method(:include?).source_location` returns `nil`.

Comment: @S.Goswami A bit late here, but the implementation for `String#include?` is C, and introspection to C source is not supported in Ruby. It's not a Ruby version thing. See source code here: https://www.rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/String:include%3F

Answer (score 44):

None of the answers so far show how to display the source code of a method **on the fly...**

It's actually very easy if you use the awesome 'method_source' gem by John Mair (the maker of Pry):
The method has to be implemented in Ruby (not C), and has to be loaded from a file (not irb).

Here's an example displaying the method source code in the Rails console with method_source:

```
  $ rails console
  > require 'method_source'
  > I18n::Backend::Simple.instance_method(:lookup).source.display
    def lookup(locale, key, scope = [], options = {})
      init_translations unless initialized?
      keys = I18n.normalize_keys(locale, key, scope, options[:separator])

      keys.inject(translations) do |result, _key|
        _key = _key.to_sym
        return nil unless result.is_a?(Hash) && result.has_key?(_key)
        result = result[_key]
        result = resolve(locale, _key, result, options.merge(:scope => nil)) if result.is_a?(Symbol)
        result
      end
    end
    => nil
```

See also:

- https://rubygems.org/gems/method_source
- https://github.com/banister/method_source
- http://banisterfiend.wordpress.com/

Comment: I always missed this feature in Ruby. Lisp can do this :)

Comment: Coming from the Clojure's `source`. This works as expected.

Comment: I get this error:  
`[1] pry(main)> RSpec.method(:class_exec).source`
`MethodSource::SourceNotFoundError: Could not locate source for class_exec!`
`from /home/vagrant/.bundle/foo/ruby/2.5.0/gems/method_source-0.9.2/lib/method_source.rb:24:in \`source_helper'`

Comment: `RSpec.method(:to_json).source_location` works fine though

Answer (score 18):

Here is how to print out the source code from ruby:

```
puts File.read(OBJECT_TO_GET.method(:METHOD_FROM).source_location[0])
```

Answer (score 14):

**Without dependencies**

```
method = SomeConstant.method(:some_method_name)
file_path, line = method.source_location
# puts 10 lines start from the method define 
IO.readlines(file_path)[line-1, 10]
```

If you want use this more conveniently, your can open the `Method` class:

```
# ~/.irbrc
class Method
  def source(limit=10)
    file, line = source_location
    if file && line
      IO.readlines(file)[line-1,limit]
    else
      nil
    end
  end
end
```

And then just call `method.source`

**With Pry** you can use the `show-method` to view a method source, and you can even see some ruby c source code with `pry-doc` installed, according pry's doc in [codde-browing](https://github.com/pry/pry#code-browsing)

> Note that we can also view C methods (from Ruby Core) using the
>   pry-doc plugin; we also show off the alternate syntax for show-method:
>
> ```
> pry(main)> show-method Array#select
>
> From: array.c in Ruby Core (C Method):
> Number of lines: 15
>
> static VALUE
> rb_ary_select(VALUE ary)
> {
>     VALUE result;
>     long i;
>
>     RETURN_ENUMERATOR(ary, 0, 0);
>     result = rb_ary_new2(RARRAY_LEN(ary));
>     for (i = 0; i < RARRAY_LEN(ary); i++) {
>         if (RTEST(rb_yield(RARRAY_PTR(ary)[i]))) {
>             rb_ary_push(result, rb_ary_elt(ary, i));
>         }
>     }
>     return result;
> }
> ```

Comment: that's a great idea for a `source` method inside the `Method` class. It would be even better if it processed the text and new when to stop printing because it reached the end of the method.

Answer (score 4):

I created the "ri_for" gem for this purpose

```
 >> require 'ri_for'
 >> A.ri_for :foo
```

... outputs the source (and location, if you're on 1.9).

GL.
-r

Comment: All this does for me is producing a segmentation fault. :(

Comment: how to reproduce seg fault? which method/class?

Answer (score 4):

Internal methods don't have source or source location (e.g. `Integer#to_s`)

```
require 'method_source'
User.method(:last).source
User.method(:last).source_location
```

Comment: These look great but didn't seem to work for me `Time.method(:month).source` gives `NameError: undefined method `month' for class `#<Class:Time>'`

Answer (score 1):

I had to implement a similar feature (grab the source of a block) as part of [Wrong](http://github.com/sconover/wrong) and you can see how (and maybe even reuse the code) in [chunk.rb](https://github.com/sconover/wrong/blob/master/lib/wrong/chunk.rb#L106) (which relies on Ryan Davis' RubyParser as well as some pretty funny source file [glomming code](https://github.com/sconover/wrong/blob/master/lib/wrong/chunk.rb#L67)). You'd have to modify it to use `Method#source_location` and maybe tweak some other things so it does or doesn't include the `def`.

BTW I think Rubinius has this feature built in. For some reason it's been left out of MRI (the standard Ruby implementation), hence this hack.

Oooh, I like some of the stuff in [method_source](https://github.com/banister/method_source)! Like [using eval to tell if an expression is valid](https://github.com/banister/method_source/blob/master/lib/method_source/code_helpers.rb#L66) (and keep glomming source lines until you stop getting parse errors, like Chunk does)...