# Ruby / Rails -- from where was a method was included?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there a way to find out from where a method was included in Ruby / Ruby on Rails?

For example, from searching the [Rails API](http://api.rubyonrails.org) I know that:

- `link_to` comes from `ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper`, and
- `pluralize` come from `ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper`

But is there a way to find out in Ruby itself? i.e. in`irb`, or the Rails console?

Comment: You might want to read this also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393096/how-can-i-get-source-code-of-a-methods-dynamically-and-also-which-file-is-this-m

Comment: And this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/175655/how-to-find-where-a-method-is-defined-at-runtime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever context you're in you can get the source location by using:

```
obj.method(:method).source_location
```

It won't give you exactly what you want, but the Rails core developers are good about properly namespacing things. The following example can be run from the rails console:

```
Time.method(:zone).source_location

["/Users/pete/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@gemset/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/core_ext/time/zones.rb", 9]
```

Then you can go to the [Rails source](https://github.com/rails/rails) and search for that file. Hint: type 't' on Github and start typing. It will bring you to [that file](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/time/zones.rb) and you can see that it is defined directly on the Time class.

Answer (score 3):

Yes:

```
@object.method(:method_name)
```

For example:

```
@object.method(:pluralize)
```

Comment: `@s = "error"; @s.pluralize(:method_name)` doesn't give `ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper`, though. Have I misunderstood?

Comment: @MatthewJeppesen Try `@s.method(:pluralize)` :)

Comment: `@s.method(:pluralize)`
`# => #<Method: String#pluralize>` ...

Comment: @MatthewJeppesen That's the correct result. `pluralize` is a method added to `String` directly. You can see its definition [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb#L25)