# How to programmatically get inner body(code) of a ruby method

Tags: ruby

Is there anyway to programmatically return the contents of a ruby method as a string? For example something like this?

```
class Foo
  def foo_method
    some_code = "goes here"
  end
end

puts Foo.method_body(:foo_method) # => "some_code = \"goes here\""
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, sort of. :-)

I had to implement a similar feature (grab the source of a block) as part of [Wrong](http://github.com/sconover/wrong) and you can see how (and maybe even reuse the code) in [chunk.rb](https://github.com/sconover/wrong/blob/master/lib/wrong/chunk.rb#L106) (which relies on Ryan Davis' RubyParser as well as some pretty funny source file [glomming code](https://github.com/sconover/wrong/blob/master/lib/wrong/chunk.rb#L67)). You'd have to modify it to use `Method#source_location` and maybe tweak some other things so it does or doesn't include the `def`.

BTW I think Rubinius has this feature built in. For some reason it's been left out of MRI (the standard Ruby implementation), hence the hack.

Update: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11544229/190135) points us to the [method_source gem](https://github.com/banister/method_source) which seems to be a (relatively) clean, one-shot solution, using a similar algorithm (keep glomming lines from a source file until you stop getting parse errors).

Comment: Thanks this is really helpful. As a bonus - Wrong might be come in handy for what I am working on, not just for the chunk file.

Comment: I hope so! I've been using Wrong as a dumping ground for all my useful testing helpers; I'd love it if others get some use out of it too.

Comment: How does this work in cases where the source file doesn't exist at runtime? E.g. AOT-compiled binaries?

Comment: Jörg: it doesn't. See [caveats](https://github.com/sconover/wrong#algorithm) in readme. `method_source` has similar limitations.