# Access a methods content without executing it in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

This question has been keeping me busy for some time now, so I hope someone has an idea on how to tackle this.

Lets take a simple `Class` with a `method` (simplified without an initialize method):

```
class MyClass
  def my_method
    page.search('//p')
  end
end
```

Now, is there a way to retrieve the content of `my_method` without executing it? I am looking to get the code that it will run when executed:

```
"page.search('//p')"
```

Is there a way to do that in Ruby?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393096/how-can-i-get-source-code-of-a-method-dynamically-and-also-which-file-is-this-me ?

Comment: If you do not necessarily need the code as a String, you can also use the AST, for example using the `ast` gem. See also https://www.igvita.com/2008/12/11/ruby-ast-for-fun-and-profit/ which describes the idea (although it is a bit dated).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's possible with [`pry`](https://github.com/pry/pry) gem, provided `my_method` source is saved in some file. `pry` adds `source` method to `Method` class:

```
require 'pry'
method = MyClass.instance_method(:my_method)
method.source
# => "  def my_method\n    page.search('//p')\n  end"
```