# Access Pry's show-source method from Ruby file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pry

Is it possible to access Pry's `show-source` method from within a Ruby file? If so, how is this done?

For example, if I had this file:

```
# testing.rb

require 'pry' 

def testing
  puts 'hi'
end

puts show-source testing
```

And ran `ruby testing.rb`, I'd like the output:

```
Owner: testing.rb
Visibility: public
Number of lines: 3

def testing
  puts 'hi'
end
```

To explain the rationale for this, I have a test stubbing a method, though the original seems to be getting called on occassion and I thought it would be handy to output the source of the call to see where it's coming from. I know there are simpler ways of doing this, though started down this rabbit hole and am interested in seeing whether this can be done :)

Running the slightly head-twisting `show-source show-source` shows a few methods within the `Pry::Command::ShowSource` class, which inherits from `Pry::Command::ShowInfo`.

`Pry::Command::ShowSource` shows three methods: `options`, `process` and `content_for`, though I've not been able to successfully call any.

My best assumption is the `content_for` method handles this, working with a code object assigned from the parent class (i.e. `Pry::CodeObject.lookup(obj_name, _pry_, :super => opts[:super])`), though I've not been able to crack this.

Anyone have any ideas or examples of doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ruby has the build-in method [*Method#source_location*](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/Method.html#method-i-source_location) which can be used to find the location of the source. The [*method_source*](https://rubygems.org/gems/method_source) gem builds upon this by extracting the source based upon the source location. However this doesn't work for methods defined in the interactive console. Methods must be defined in a file.

Here is an example:

```
require 'set'
require 'method_source'

puts Set.method(:[]).source_location
# /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/set.rb
# 74
#=> nil

puts Set.method(:[]).source
# def self.[](*ary)
#   new(ary)
# end
#=> nil
```

Keep in mind that all core Ruby methods are written in C and return `nil` as source location. `1.method(:+).source_location #=> nil` The standard library is written in Ruby itself. Therefore the example above works for *Set* methods.

Comment: Perfect - thanks @JohanWentholt. That fits what I'm after perfectly. Appreciate the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can access source of a method without using `pry` with a [Object#method](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/Object.html#method-i-method) and `Method#source_location` as described in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46966145/580346

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Pry to show you the source code of a method (not just the location of the source):

```rb
require "pry"

identifier = "MyClass#my_instance_function"
code_object = Pry::CodeObject.lookup(identifier, Pry.new)

puts code_object.source # => ...
# def my_instance_function(arg)
#   puts "my arg #{arg}
# end
```

...where `identifier` is a standard Pry identifier for a method, such as `"MyClass#my_instance_method"` or `"MyNamespace.my_static_function"`.